# Android sqlite Cursor value to a textbox

Tags: android, sqlite

```
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView123);

Cursor sum = dbObject.rawQuery("SELECT Sum(Volume) FROM SHARE WHERE _id2 LIKE ?",
                 new String[] { "%" + val1 + "%" });
```

how to get the **sum** value to a TextView?

thank you in advance,

Comment: set like if(sum.moveToFirst())   text.setText(Integer.toString(sum.getInt(0)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.startManagingCursor(sum); //or any (Activity) .startManagingCursor

sum.moveToFirst();

text.setText(sum.getString(0));
```

Comment: Thank you for ur valued support